# Chrono time counter is inaccurate when machine goes to sleep in the middle of execution?

Tags: c++, windows, c++-chrono

I have the code sample bellow to measure the execution time of some piece of code:

```
int main()
{   
    auto before = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    Sleep(30000);

    auto after = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int duration = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds> ((after - before)).count());
    cout << duration << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Normally it works fine and prints out 30 in the `cout` statement.

However, during testing I observed that if the computer were to go to sleep in between the `auto before = ...` statement and the `auto after = ...` statement (due to inactivity or whatever other reason), then the printed out time also counts the entire time the machine was asleep. This makes perfect sense since we are comparing a timepoint from before the machine going to sleep and one with after.

So my question is how can I make it so that the duration the machine was asleep is not counted in my final duration? Probably will need a ticker that doesn't increment while machine is asleep rather than timepoint measurements but I'm not aware of such a ticker.

This is a Windows specific question. As I understand, MacOS has [mach_absolute_time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1462446-mach_absolute_time) which is exactly what I'm looking for in windows. I'm using MSVC 19.29.30147.0 as my compiler.

Comment: "*I realized that if the computer were to go to sleep in between the auto before = ... statement and the auto after = ... statement*" Did you just think about this, or did you actually see it happen? I don't know exactly what the behavior of `steady_clock` is under sleep patterns, but I wouldn't merely presume that this would be the case.

Comment: *"This is a Windows specific question"* - Have you tried using [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter)?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it consistently. Waited for the 30 second sleep, manually put my machine to sleep and when I turned it back on it continued to execute and printed a time greater than 30 depending on how long I waited.

Comment: @MooseBoys Unfortunately the problem reproduces with that function as well.

Comment: @finalreq This indicates the system is not suspended, but is rather in a partial sleep state. According to MSDN, newer versions of msvc implement both `steady_clock` and `high_resolution_clock` using QPC. `std::chrono` was unfortunately written without much regard for the plethora of various sleep states supported on modern computers, so they're not really useful for measuring time across power state changes. If your goal is to measure total time *running on a core*, you'll have to use [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/event-tracing-for-windows--etw-).

Comment: What about `GetTickCount` ? Since it's a system tick maybe it isn't incremented when the system sleeps. If you want to keep the high resolution clock, you could use both and only use `GetTickCount` to correct your precise clock.

Comment: @ElderBug Reproduces with GetTickCount as well.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer. `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTimePrecise()` sounds like the right fit based on documentation. Will test and update the post if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around and testing it out, the solution is to use [QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/realtimeapiset/nf-realtimeapiset-queryunbiasedinterrupttime)

> Gets the current unbiased interrupt-time count, in units of 100 nanoseconds. The unbiased interrupt-time count does not include time the system spends in sleep or hibernation.

Running the following code snippet, I manually put my machine to sleep while the program was stuck on the sleep statement and I observed that the second print out consistently outputs 15 seconds regardless of how long I leave my machine in a sleeping state. However, the first print-out that uses `GetTickCount64` will include the amount of time the machine was asleep.

```
int main()
{

    ULONGLONG before_query, after_query= 0;
    QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime(&before_query);
    auto beforeticks = GetTickCount64();
   
    Sleep(15000);

    QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime(&after_query);
  
    auto afterticks = GetTickCount64();


    cout << "Ticks from gettickcount64 is " << (double (afterticks-beforeticks))/1000 << endl;

    cout << "Unbiased time measure is " << double((after_query - before_query)/10000000) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the easiest way is to use a counter that is incremented each second. This is easily implemented with threads:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

class ellapsed_counter {
    std::atomic<bool> finished = false;
    std::atomic<unsigned int> value = 0;
    
    std::thread worker { [this] {
        while(!finished) {
            value++;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        }
    } };

public:
    void finish() noexcept { 
        finished = true; 
        if(worker.joinable()) worker.join();
    }
    unsigned int ellapsed() const noexcept { return value; }
};
```

This will keep incrementing on 1s intervals (probably with some error) as long as the process is running and should cease so when it is sleeping.
You can use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    ellapsed_counter counter;
    unsigned int last = 0, count = 0;

    while(count < 10) {
        count = counter.ellapsed();
        if(count != last) {
            last = count;
            std::cout << count << std::endl;
        }
    }
    counter.finish();

    return 0;
}
```

This will count from 1 to 10 seconds and exit.